# Why is there a Google Plus ad on the main Ask Different site?

Tags: discussion, design, advertising

Is the google plus ad a community promotion advertisement or something else?

I clicked it but nothing shows if I don't log into google - what is this?

```
https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?service=webupdates&passive=1209600&continue=https://m.google.com/app/contacts/mp/144/continue/?unauth%3D1%26login%3D1&followup=https://m.google.com/app/contacts/mp/144/continue/?unauth%3D1%26login%3D1&btmpl=mobile&ltmpl=mobilex
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I ended up at https://plus.google.com/101120115153580954446/posts when I clicked the ad (same destination and largely identical content whether I am logged into a Google account or not).

The above-linked page seems to be a Google+ account for “Stack Exchange” to post various things: “interesting” questions from various SE sites (similar the [SE Twitter account](http://twitter.com/stackexchange)), but also podcast episode notifications, and some other SE-related news. It seems very similar to the [SE page on Facebook](http://www.facebook.com/stackexchange).

Joel Spolsky recently [tweeted that “You can also follow Stack Exchange on Google+”](https://twitter.com/spolsky/status/141912830462005248) with a link to a [Google+ search for “Stack Exchange”](https://plus.google.com/u/0/s/Stack%20Exchange) (this was right after he [tweeted](https://twitter.com/spolsky/status/141911133505335296) about the symmetry of SE on Facebook and Facebook on SE: facebook.com/stackexchange, facebook.stackoverflow.com).

The ad itself seems to be just one of the SE-promoting ads that SE injects into its sites (questions from other SE sites, site proposals from Area 51, “Join us on Facebook”, “Join us on G+”, et cetera).

Comment: The link you have above resolves to this for me - you sure you're not logged in to google? https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?service=webupdates&passive=1209600&continue=https://m.google.com/app/contacts/mp/144/continue/?unauth%3D1%26login%3D1&followup=https://m.google.com/app/contacts/mp/144/continue/?unauth%3D1%26login%3D1&btmpl=mobile&ltmpl=mobilex

Comment: @bmike: I originally just did a simple “logout” in my normal browser (Safari). Since you asked, I tried my first URL in two browsers (Chrome, Firefox) that I usually do not use (and with which I have never logged into a Google account). I got the same result as a plain logout: the G+ page for Stack Exchange with no user-specific content. Further, under a brand new OS-user-account (freshly created for this test) two browsers (Safari and Firefox) also gave the same result.

Comment: Awesome - and head scratchingly odd. Thanks for the above and beyond testing.

Comment: The `m.google.com` and `mobilex` bits of your URL might indicate that Google is trying to serve you some kind of mobile adaptation. The page rendered when I visit your URL (a login page) certainly looks like it might be “small screen optimized” (minimal styling and content, with everything in a narrow column).

Comment: Reproduced: If I “sign out” of Google, have Safari set its User-Agent to an iPhone variant, and then load my first URL, I end up at a URL very much like yours (`852` instead of `144`). When I am signed in to Google (with the UA set to be like an iPhone), I do get a mobilified G+ Stack Exchange page. I guess G+ is not quite mobile-ready (or they just do not want to render otherwise public pages for visitors that are not signed into Google).